Substitute /Concatenate
The apostrophe is this string is breaking a power automate flow. I would like the name to just be "Sheerin, Jon" Instead of "Sheerin, Jon O'Hare" and remove everything else after Jon.
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(B2,E2), " ", ""), ",", "")

Better hope actress D'Arcy Carden doesn't join your app. Fix the flow?

A Rather easier way is to get rid of the apostrophe - as Ceejayoz said: getting rid of everything after apostrophe can be a data disaster.
Getting rid of the problematic ' is simple. Here's how you can replace it with an empty string - or a space if you'd like.
replace(outputs('Name'),'''','') //yes the four '''' there


